# Comparing variable to constant doesn't work?

Tags: c, constants

Having a background of programming in PHP and Javascript, it's sometimes hard to wrap my head around the behavior of C and C compilers in certain situations. One such situation that I've just come across (programming an AVR ATmega16 microcontroller) is comparing variables to defined constants, which apparently doesn't work:

```
#define SYS_STATE_IDLE 0;
//...

char systemState = SYS_STATE_IDLE;
/...

// Main function body
int main(void) {

    //...

    for(;;) {
        // Determine if a new key was pressed
        if (keyPressed()) {
            switch (systemState) {
                case SYS_STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (AVR GCC) throws the following exception at the first `case`:

```
../SunTrackerMainController.c:103: error: expected ':' or '...' before ';' token
../SunTrackerMainController.c:103: error: expected expression before ':' token
```

I've tried the `if` statement as well:

```
if (systemState == SYS_STATE_IDLE) {
    // whatever
}
```

but the outcome is basically the same:

```
../SunTrackerMainController.c:109: error: expected ')' before ';' token
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if it helps you remember, #define is for the preprocessor (not a C statement which requires the ; to separate statements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remember that the preprocessor replaces macros *verbatim*, so whenever it sees `SYS_STATE_IDLE` it replaces it with `0;`, so the statement

```
case SYS_STATE_IDLE:
```

will be transformed to

```
case 0;:
```

The same when you try to use it inside the `if`, you get

```
if (systemState == 0;)
```

after macro replacement.

The preprocessor, as its name implies, is a step that is run before the compiler (the "pre" part) to process the source. It is its own micro-language inside the larger language that is C, and one that is terminated by newlines and not semicolons.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `;` from the end of your `#define`. At the moment the preprocessor is inserting a semicolon wherever you use `SYS_STATE_IDLE`, which you don't want.

```
#define SYS_STATE_IDLE 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In `#define` Whatever you write after the definition name becomes its value. In this case, `0;` is becoming the value of `SYS_STATE_IDLE` which should not include a semicolon being used as a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

After the preprocessor, your code looks like this:

```
case 0;: {
```

Now you understand what is this `;` the compiler is complaining about? To fix that, remove `;` from `define`.

Comment: Nope, the expression inside the `switch()` will not be replaced, `systemState` is not a preprocessor macro, it's a normal variable.

Comment: The `systemState` is a variable, it's assigned from the macro earlier in the code, but it's still a normal variable. There is no macro replacement of `systemState` as it's not a macro.

Comment: This is wrong. After pre-processing the code would look like `case 0;:`

Comment: Yes, but not *there*, because the OP din't use `SYS_STATE_IDLE` there. Your problem description is correct, but it's just the wrong place.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks.. that was a typo :) Corrected. (I wouldn't downvote for such a typo..)